# How do I sort my references in LaTeX by order of appearance, whilst still showing URLs?

Tags: latex, bibliography

I want to sort my references by order of appearance rather than alphabetically, and I'm led to believe that I need to use the 'unsrt' style to do that. However, the 'unsrt' style doesn't support displaying URLs in the Bibliography (at least, not as far as I can see anyway).

How can I display URLs in my bibliography, whilst still sorting it by order of appearance?

I'm using BibDesk to create the .bib file, and a typical entry that I need to display with a URL looks like:

```
@webpage{iasi,
Author = {ESA},
Date-Added = {2011-04-11 09:12:00 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2011-04-11 10:09:33 +0100},
Keywords = {iasi, so2, satellite},
Lastchecked = {11th April 2011},
Title = {{M}et{O}p - {IASI}},
Url = {http://www.esa.int/esaME/iasi.html},
Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.esa.int/esaME/iasi.html}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are versions of `unsrt.bst` that support the URL field, such as [Urlbst](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst/urlbst.html).

Comment: Using `\bibliographystyle{unsrturl}` (downloaded from Urlbst) compiles fine, but doesn't seem to actually display the URLs in the bibliography?

Comment: @James.  Funny: I can see that http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst/unsrturl.bst has code for including url in the webpage type (as well as all other document types).  Could you put up a minimum working example?  You might prefer to ask this qn again at http://tex.stackexchange.com/ - you might get a faster answer.

Comment: My mistake, it is working - I'd just forgotten to recompile the BibTeX before compiling the LaTeX.